# How to increase the clickable area of checkbox for touch screen

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox, mouseevent

I'm trying to increase the clickable area for a checkbox in label.

However, there are also 2 anchor tags in it, and when I try to click on the checkbox on tablet, I get redirected to the hyperlink because the clickable area for checkbox is small, but the area for anchor tag is bigger.

I need to make both of them clickable on tablet, but be able to click on the checkbox too.

Here is the current layout:

[image]

Since I also can't address :before as a DOM element on jQuery, I can't also modify it. 
Is there any recommendations ?

```
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 1px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: transparent;
}
```

```
<label class="form-label checkout-label">
 <span class="form-label-forced-span">
 I agree with the <a href="$url('Page-Show', 'cid', 'policy-link')$" 
 target="_blank" aria-label="confidentiality and protection 
 policy">confidentiality and protection policy</a> and <a href="$url('Page- 
 Show', 'cid', 'terms-and-uses')$" target="_blank" aria-label="the terms of use">the 
 terms of use</a>.
 </span>
</label>
```

Comment: Please also share your html

Comment: @TVBZ Shared the related html code above. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't get the reason for the peudo element producing a square before the labels...

I suggest you to use some [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) rules to change the checkbox size depending on the screen size:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 736px){
  [type="checkbox"]{
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    transform: translateY(0.5em);  /* To move it down a bit... */
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<label class="form-label checkout-label">
  <span class="form-label-forced-span">
    I agree with the <a href="$url('Page-Show', 'cid', 'policy-link')$" 
                        target="_blank" aria-label="confidentiality and protection 
      policy">confidentiality and protection policy</a> and <a href="$url('Page- 
      Show', 'cid', 'terms-and-uses')$" target="_blank" aria-label="the terms of use">the 
    terms of use</a>.
  </span>
</label>
```

On screens narrower than 736px, this will "double" the checkbox size. Have a look at the [common breakpoints](https://medium.com/@uiuxlab/the-most-used-responsive-breakpoints-in-2017-of-mine-9588e9bd3a8a).

---

**EDIT**
From your code... If you use `margin-top` and `margin-left`, instead of `top` and `left` to position the pseudo element, it works quite fine.

See here:

```css
.container{
  width:90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  /*left: 0;
  top: 1px;*/

  margin-left: -2.5em;
  margin-top: -1em;

  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="acceptPolicy">
  <label class="form-label checkout-label" for="acceptPolicy">
    <span class="form-label-forced-span">
      I agree with the <a href="$url('Page-Show', 'cid', 'policy-link')$" 
                          target="_blank" aria-label="confidentiality and protection 
        policy">confidentiality and protection policy</a> and <a href="$url('Page- 
        Show', 'cid', 'terms-and-uses')$" target="_blank" aria-label="the terms of use">the 
      terms of use</a>.
    </span>
  </label>
</div>
```

I added the `for=` attribute on the label...
I also added a container to it just to "move" the label to the right a bit. And I changed the border color just for fun.

Comment: Hello ! It's done in the project to increase the clickable area of checkbox. The checkbox is also checked when you click on the label except the anchor tags. The problem is, I can't edit the layout so it should remain the same. Do you have any other recommendations that can increase the clickable area ?

Comment: *«The checkbox is also checked when you click on the label»* Using a `for=` attribute? Is the checkbox inside or outside the label? (I assumed outside, right before because of your posted CSS).

Comment: pseudo element can be clicked if produced from a form element, a link or an element which has a tabindex attribute. exemple with label and checkbox : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/WWNNwP they can be used to increase the clickable area https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bJGGeQ

Comment: @G-Cyr:mmm Ok, I had in mind that pseudo elements are not accessible to JS /jQuery... So you're right. I suggest you to post your answer using OP's HTML. ;)

Comment: No, it's inside the label and I'm using for attribute in label. I needed to make some edits on code since can't share all of them. I'm looking for a jQuery or javascript based solution with a click event based because this is what I can think of to fix it. Do you think it is possible to increase the clickable area by overlapping the other elements for a certain area ?

Comment: you are right too, they are virtual box, no way to access them via js, but the parent should still catch the mouse event ;) but the funny part is to sort the click event from the label and the link inside the label ... both are supposed to be clickable....

Comment: @G-Cyr Thanks a lot for sharing the pens ! However, I need to also enable the hyperlink click together with the checkbox click. But the checkbox click should cut some area of the anchor text to make it clickable for a bigger area. If I address the parent, the checkbox becomes clickable, but anchor tags get disabled. That's why, I need to specifically target that checkbox and increase the clickable area. I'm also open for suggestions if you have any !

Comment: I used this @media to increase the size of checkboxes on small screens and it is so simple and clean. Thank you!